# centering two views in Navigation titleView

Tags: ios, swift, view, subviews

I want my application to behave like this:

[image]

**It is important to have the exact behavior for my NavigationItem.titleView**

I followed these steps so far:

I am creating three views programmatically in my application:

(1) `container` => holds (2) and (3) => has a gestureRecognizer attached

```
   let container = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,40))
```

(2) `imageContainer` => has an image

```
        let imageContainer = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30))
        imageContainer.image = UIImage(named: "mock.jpg")
```

(3) `textContainer` => has some text

```
        let textContainer = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 180, 20))
        textContainer.text = "Group xY"
```

**Following I am setting the center of the images to align them:**

```
    imageContainer.center = CGPointMake(container.frame.size.width  / 2,
        container.frame.size.height / 2)
textContainer.center = CGPointMake(container.frame.size.width  / 2,
            container.frame.size.height / 2)
```

Now I am adding all the subViews to my View and setting

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = (1)
```

**Starting the app shows, that the titleView's elements aren't properly aligned**

[image]

Is there a way to implement this exact behavior correctly?

**Note:** don't worry about the circular image. I know how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the size of textContainer to be closer to the bounds of the text. You can do this by calling `sizeToFit` then you need to set the imageContainer to be on the left of the text so the center of the image should be half the width of the image plus a buffer from the start of the text. You could do that by saying `imageContainer.center = CGPointMake(textContainer.frame.minX - imageContainer.frame.size.width * 0.5 - buffer,container.frame.size.height / 2)`. Your code should look something like:

```
let container = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,40))
let buffer:CGFloat = 8.0
let maxWidth:CGFloat = 120.0

let imageContainer = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30))
imageContainer.image = UIImage(named: "profile.jpg")

let textContainer = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 180, 20))
textContainer.text = "Group xY"
textContainer.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
textContainer.minimumScaleFactor = 0.95

textContainer.sizeToFit()
textContainer.frame.size.width = min(maxWidth, textContainer.frame.size.width)
textContainer.center = CGPointMake(container.frame.size.width  / 2,
                                   container.frame.size.height / 2)
imageContainer.center = CGPointMake(textContainer.frame.minX - imageContainer.frame.size.width * 0.5 - buffer,
                                    container.frame.size.height / 2)

container.addSubview(imageContainer)
container.addSubview(textContainer)
```

Which will give you [image] for your container.

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot. Is there a way to set a max width of the view ? if i put a longer text in it, the whole Navbar is populated, but I would also like to have my Navigationbar.barButtonitems

Comment: I updated my answer. You can just check the width of the label after `sizeToFit` if it's larger than the largest width you want set it to maximum width else leave as is (e.g. `min(maxWidth, textContainer.frame.size.width)` You can also adjust the labels scale factor to have shrink to fit though you probably don't want to shrink it a bunch for a title.